# Patterns for Mongodb c# client

Tags: c#, mongodb, singleton, repository, data-access-layer

I want to use mongodb for a project.

OK yes, i able to connect to it and do things.

However, I want to be able to wrap the mongodb driver around a wrapper so if i want to change the database, i want to be easily change it.

Repository pattern looks like something I can use with Mongodb, but I m kinda over thinking where to start the connection? should i use a singleton ?

Mongodb docs says that it is thread safe, so if i create a single MongoServer and single MongoDatabase classes via Singleton and per collection, I can have a method that return a collections.

Is this a bad design?

What would be a better design?

I want to use singleton to create connection to database cause I dont want to keep creating connection per thread, if there is already a persistent connection.

any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Connections are pooled so if you are done with it in one thread, it will be eligible for reuse in other threads
- You can do repository pattern down to `Collection` level. That's how it's done in side MongoDB Driver anyway
- I don't really see the need to do it anyway. You can use `MongoDatabase.Create(MongoUrl)` method with connection string. It already does the abstraction for you in terms of server and database name

Comment: well i dont want to do MongoDatabase.Create(MongoUrl) everywhere i m using it. what s the point of doing the same thing over and over?

Comment: You can definitely store a reference to a MongoDatabase somewhere in your application if you prefer. No one is saying you have to call MongoDatabase.Create over and over, just that it's one of the options available to you and that it doesn't create extra instances of MongoDatabase when called with the same parameters.

Comment: You also asked this question on Google Groups and there is more information there: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/821f66f7727e381d

Comment: "MongoDatabase.Create(MongoUrl)" is now obsolete.